# Can't see external hard drive on Mac or PC

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

As mentioned in the title, I can't see my external hard drive on Mac finder and PC. I checked on Mac disk utility and it does appear over there.

I thought about trying to repair it but i'm afraid i'll lose its content as it is very important.

My external drive is WesternDigital. Capacity of 500GB if i'm not mistaking... Self powered and connected via USB.

Comment: It might have something to do with the Western Digital SmartWare software that comes preinstalled on the WD external drive. I have a WD external drive, and I uninstalled SmartWare and the drive is working fine. SmartWare keeps your backup files in folders with technobabble names to lock you into their product line. Even if you uninstall SmartWare, your backup files will still be where they were backed up somewhere on the drive, but you'll have to search for them.

Comment: I have deleted (not uninstalled) the things that were installed on the device... That might have not been the smartest thing to do.. :) Could that cause this? Is there a way back?